# How to connect WebBrowser to IE instance?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser

I want control IE application using WebBrowser class. Is there any way to do that?

**UPDATE**
i want to get ability to inject scripts into HTML-page, execute functions of that script and ability to call c# object metods from script.

When i use WebBrowser component i can do that. But i want to interact with separated IE window, not with component.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to control? Could you provide a little more details about your scenario and what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSHtml and ShDocview to work with IE Instance.

Check this link:
http://65.39.148.34/KB/toolbars/MicrosoftMshtml.aspx

Comment: Tnx. But this is only a part of solution i still can't make call from JS to c# object.

Comment: normally I would create a web method to call server side code from JS or a web page that will accept query string parameter as input and use Response.Write to return the out and then call Response.End